# Fill Metadata with PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint, metadata, power-automate

im only getting gpt-genereted suggestions in the microsoft community hub. im asking your to help me with a flow in microsofts power automate.

Goal:

- I have a document library that can also show metadata like creation date, creator, month, year.
- To make the user experience as good as possible i want theese columns automatically be filled when a new document is created.

My attempt:

Trigger is "When a file is created (properties only)
Action is "Get file metadata" -> "Update file properties"

No matter what i tried so far the flow is either not working or throws me an error like "ResponseSwaggerSchemaValidationFailure"